# Implementing FCFS CPU Scheduler (Wait time function)

Tags: c#, algorithm

Process Data:
process goes {CPU burst, I/O time, CPU burst, I/O time, CPU burst, I/O time,…….., last CPU burst}

I split the data into two arrays. cpu burst and io_burst

P1 {4,24,5,73,3,31,5,27,4,33,6,43,4,64,5,19,2}

P2 {18,31,19,35,11,42,18,43,19,47,18,43,17,51,19,32,10}

P3 {6,18,4,21,7,19,4,16,5,29,7,21,8,22,6,24,5}

P4 {17,42,19,55,20,54,17,52,15,67,12,72,15,66,14}

P5 {5,81,4,82,5,71,3,61,5,62,4,51,3,77,4,61,3,42,5}

P6 {10,35,12,41,14,33,11,32,15,41,13,29,11}

P7 {21,51,23,53,24,61,22,31,21,43,20}

P8 {11,52,14,42,15,31,17,21,16,43,12,31,13,32,15}

I'm mostly having a hard time calculating the wait time for this. I made a class process which is here

```
class Process
{
    //public Process(string name, int arrival, int cpuburst,int ioburst, int priority)
    //{
    //    this.name = name;
    //    this.arrival = arrival;
    //    this.cpuburst = cpuburst;
    //    this.ioburst = ioburst;
    //    this.priority = priority;
    //}
    public Process()
    {

    }
    public string name;
    public int arrival;
    public int[] cpuburst;
    public int []ioburst;
    public int priority;
    public int totburst;
    public int wait;
    public int end;
    public int start;
    public int contextswitch;
    public int response;
    public int turnAround;

    //public int contextswitch;
    public double cpu_utilization;
    public double avwaitingtime;
    public double avturnaroundtime;
    public double avresponse;

}
```

}

heres how I'm initializing, I made cpuburst and io_burst the same size by adding some zeroes to the end of the array

```
void initialize_process()
    {
        List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
        Process p1 = new Process();
        p1.arrival = 0;
        p1.end = 0;
        p1.name = "P1";
        p1.cpuburst = new int[] { 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 2 ,0};
        p1.ioburst = new int[] { 24, 73, 31, 27, 33, 43, 64, 19, 0, 0 };
        p1.totburst = 38;
        processes.Add(p1);

        Process p2 = new Process();
        p2.arrival = 0;
        p2.name = "P2";
        p2.end = 0;
        p2.cpuburst = new int[] { 18, 19, 11, 18, 19, 18, 17, 19, 10, 0 };
        p2.ioburst = new int[] { 31, 35, 42, 43, 47, 43, 51, 32, 0, 0 };
        p2.totburst = 149;
        processes.Add(p2);

        Process p3 = new Process();
        p3.arrival = 0;
        p3.end = 0;
        p3.name = "P3";
        p3.cpuburst = new int[]{ 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 5 ,0};
        p3.ioburst = new int[] { 18, 21, 19, 16, 29, 21, 22, 24, 0, 0 };
        p3.totburst = 52;
        processes.Add(p3);

        Process p4 = new Process();
        p4.arrival = 0;
        p4.end = 0;
        p4.name = "P4";
        p4.cpuburst = new int[] { 17, 19, 20, 17, 15, 12, 15, 14,0,0 };
        p4.ioburst = new int[] { 42, 55, 54, 52, 67, 72, 66, 0, 0, 0 };
        p4.totburst = 129;
        processes.Add(p4);

        Process p5 = new Process();
        p5.arrival = 0;
        p5.end = 0;
        p5.name = "P5";
        p5.cpuburst = new int[]{ 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5 };
        p5.ioburst = new int[] { 81, 82, 71, 61, 62, 51, 77, 61, 42, 0 };
        p5.totburst = 41;
        processes.Add(p5);

        Process p6 = new Process();
        p6.arrival = 0;
        p6.end = 0;
        p6.name = "P6";
        p6.cpuburst = new int[] { 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 13, 11,0,0,0 };
        p6.ioburst = new int[] { 35, 41, 33, 32, 41, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        p6.totburst = 86;
        processes.Add(p6);

        Process p7 = new Process();
        p7.arrival = 0;
        p7.end = 0;
        p7.name = "P7";
        p7.cpuburst = new int[]{ 21, 23, 24, 22, 21, 20,0,0,0,0 };
        p7.ioburst = new int[] { 51, 53, 61, 31, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        p7.totburst = 131;
        processes.Add(p7);

        Process p8 = new Process();
        p8.arrival = 0;
        p8.end = 0;
        p8.name = "P8";
        p8.cpuburst = new int[] { 11, 14, 15, 17, 16, 12, 13, 15, 0, 0 };
        p8.ioburst = new int[] { 52, 42, 31, 21, 43, 31, 32, 0, 0, 0 };
        p8.totburst = 113;
        processes.Add(p8);




        FCFS(processes);
        SJF(processes);

    }
```

In my FCFS function I call other functions to perform the calculations

```
void FCFS(List<Process> p)
    {
        output.Items.Add("After FCFS");
        output.Items.Add("-------------------------------------------------------");
        wait(p);
        turnaroundtime(p);
        responsetime(p);
        completeoutputlist(p);
    }
```

my attempts at wait time have failed and I really don't know how to best approach this. I want to get these values calculated here so then I can call them in my other functions.
I'm mostly stuck on how to take I/o time into account when calculating the clock

the processes are doing I/O at the same time one other process is running. So, I/O should be decremented as timer is incremented for every process doing I/O.
multiple processes can be doing i/o at the same time. So you would need a list of processes that are doing i/o.
really just need some guidance in this part.

```
void wait(List<Process> p)
    {


        /* Goal keep track of context switches. - p.contextswitch
         *      Keep track of the first time it enters to get response time  - p.start
         *      Keep track of when the process ends - so later we can calc turnaround time p.end
         *      then tweak some functions so it works again
         *      
         */



    }
```

Before I was doing something like this

```
void wait(List<Process> p)
    {


        /* Goal keep track of context switches. - p.contextswitch
         *      Keep track of the first time it enters to get response time  - p.start
         *      Keep track of when the process ends - so later we can calc turnaround time p.end
         *      then tweak some functions so it works again
         *      
         */

        int k = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int clock = 0;
        int contextswitch = 0;
        int cpuready = 0;
        int ioready = 0;
        double avwaitingtime = 0;


        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < p.Count; i++)
            {
                //cpuready = p[i].cpuburst[k];
                //ioready = p[i].ioburst[k];




                clock += p[i].cpuburst[k];

                    //sets arrival time P1
                    if (i == 0 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[0].arrival = 0;

                    }
                    //sets arrival time P2
                    if (i == 1 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[1].arrival = clock;

                    }
                    //sets arrival time P3
                    if (i == 2 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[2].arrival = clock;

                    }
                    //sets arrival time P4
                    if (i == 3 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[3].arrival = clock;

                    }
                    //sets arrival time P5
                    if (i == 4 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[4].arrival = clock;

                    }
                    //sets arrival time P6
                    if (i == 5 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[5].arrival = clock;

                    }
                    //sets arrival time P7
                    if (i == 6 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[6].arrival = clock;

                    }
                    //sets arrival time P8
                    if (i == 7 && k == 0)
                    {
                        p[7].arrival = clock;

                    }
                    //ADDS TO THE CONTEXT SWITCH CONTER
                    contextswitch += 1;

                    //Checks the first row and the last column
                    if (i == 0 && k == 8)
                    {

                        p[0].end = clock;
                    }
                    //Checks the 2nd row and the last column
                    if (i == 1 && k == 8)
                    {

                        p[1].end = clock;
                    }
                    //Checks the 3rd row and the last column
                    if (i == 2 && k == 8)
                    {

                        p[2].end = clock;
                    }
                    //Checks the 4th row and the last column
                    if (i == 3 && k == 7)
                    {

                        p[3].end = clock;
                    }
                    //Checks the 5th row and the last column
                    if (i == 4 && k == 9)
                    {

                        p[4].end = clock;
                    }
                    //Checks the 6th row and the last column
                    if (i == 5 && k == 6)
                    {

                        p[5].end = clock;
                    }
                    //Checks the 7th row and the last column
                    if (i == 6 && k == 5)
                    {

                        p[6].end = clock;
                    }
                    //Checks the 8th row and the last column
                    if (i == 7 && k == 7)
                    {

                        p[7].end = clock;
                    }




           }


       }
        output.Items.Add(clock);    
        double waitsum = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                //CALCS THE WAIT TIME 
                p[i].wait = (p[i].end- p[i].totburst);
               // output.Items.Add(p[i].wait);
                //CALCS THE WAITSUM
                waitsum += p[i].wait;
            }
            //calcs avg wait time
            avwaitingtime = (waitsum / 8.0);

            //output.Items.Add(avg);




        output.Items.Add(contextswitch);
        cpu_utilization(p, contextswitch,clock);
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            p[i].avwaitingtime = avwaitingtime;

        }

    }
```

any sort of ideas on how to approach this would be tons of help, thanks!

Comment: You are simulating the scheduler of an OS, have you worked out a structured english 'specification' of how the scheduler schedules? That would include how tasks get into the scheduler to be scheduled, and how the scheduler chooses which process to schedule - FCFS (are you assuming the processes are initially scheduled p1...p9?) or SJF, or prioritised, or.... whatever. Without that specification you don't know what to code, as you have discovered.

Comment: FCFS non prememptive, I also need to do SJF non prememptive and a MLFQ but right now I'm focusing on just FCFS. We're taking the process as ordered so p1 - p8. I think I know how to functions but just having hard time figuring out how to correctly handle the clock with the i/o time. Heres a screenshot of my specification if I haven't been clear about it. http://puu.sh/s4tO1/a9bb7efa62.png, http://puu.sh/s4tRa/0912f13521.png